# In regular polygon ABCDE..., we have ∠ACD = 120°. How many sides does the polygon have?

Tags: geometry, polygons

In regular polygon ABCDE..., we have ∠ACD = 120°. How many sides does the polygon have?

How would I start with solving this? AC would have different lengths depending on the polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that there exist totally $n$ sides along the vertexes $D,E,\cdots,A$. Notice that $$120^o=\angle ACD \overset{m}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat{DE\cdots A}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 360^o\cdot \frac{n}{n+3}.$$

Thus, $n=6.$ As a result, the number of the sides of the polygon is $n+3=9.$

Comment: Alright what the hell. I was adding a comment and it edited your answer instead... I'm sorry if that deleted any changes you've made, it was not my intention. EDIT: I see now, it popped up an 'edit summary box' right where my comment box was when I went to copy/paste some LaTeX and I happily added my 'comment' there.

Comment: Either way, I'm not too familiar with geometric notation, could you explain what $\overset{m} =$ and $\widehat{DE\cdots A}$ mean?

Comment: Yep. That is to say, $\angle ACD$ equals half of the central angle opposite to the arc $DE\cdots A$.

Comment: did you mean n=9?

Comment: @ShadyAF yes,a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The interior angle of a regular polygon is $$\angle ABC=\angle BCD=\frac{180(n-2)}{n}$$
Now the triangle ABC is isosceles, so $$\angle BCA = \frac12(180-\frac{180(n-2)}{n})  \\ \angle BCA+\angle ACD = \angle BCD \\ \frac12(180-\frac{180(n-2)}{n})+120=\frac{180(n-2)}{n}$$
This gives $n=9$.